# Python Message to String error

Tags: email, python-2.7, imap

I am trying to parse the contents of the body of an email. So far I have the program working so that it prints the body of an email but I am not sure how to parse it because it is a `Message` object.

My code is for printing the message is:

```
msg = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
msgBody = msg.get_payload()[0]
```

this would return something like

```
-------------------------------------------------------
From nobody Mon Nov 03 10:27:03 2014
Content-Type: text/plain;

 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hi Kevin,

Thank you for applying to join MyCrowd. We have received your application and are reviewing it.

The MyCrowd Team

If you would like to unsubscribe and stop receiving these emails click here: http://mail.mycrowd.com/wf/unsubscribe

-------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to do something like `msgBody.find("MyCrowd")` but I keep getting the error:

```
Message instance has no attribute 'find'
```

Comment: Have you read the [`Message` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message)?

Comment: Yea, I saw that there was an as_string method but its now returning an error function object has no attribute find.

Comment: You will probably need to **call** `.as_string()` (note parentheses).